# Fieldbus vs IIOT Difference

Tags: industry-4.0

I am trying to understand the difference between Fieldbus and Industrial Internet of Things. Looking at the architectures, they both look very similar.

1. Fieldbus is a hierarchical connection databus that progressively integrates sensors, actuators and end devices to PLCs & control elements and then control elements to computers and IT systems.
2. IIoT tries to accomplish integration between IT/Enterprise System on one end with end devices (actuators, sensors etc...) on the other end with some sort of "gateway" in the middle.

Now my question is:

1. Is IIOT a sort of supersystem of existing interconnection protocols like fieldbus & modbus?

OR

2. Is it  special interconnection between business applications vs operations management systems (Ex: Computer software at head level of fieldbus)

OR

3. Is it a disruptor to push computing to the edge (sensor, actuators etc...) on one hand which is directly connected to enterprise/it software on the cloud on the other hand?

How does IIOT relate to the industrial networks protocol that currently exist?